# CRUD and default values

Tags: playframework

Hi is there any simple way how to deal with default value for create CRUD template in Play?
(for example value of integer different from default 0)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a bug raised regarding this in one of the [google group threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/wmd1X_B0MwI). It was suggested the best way was to rely on the default constructor to specfiy the default values for fields.

I have tested this, and it works fine. My test was to create a simple Model class, setting a default value for one of the fields, and then using the default CRUD settings.

```
package models;

@javax.persistence.Entity
public class Person extends play.db.jpa.Model {

    public int age;
    public String name;

    public Person() {
        age = 18;
    }
}
```

If I go to the CRUD screen, the age shows as 18.

Comment: @kvgr Since this answer works great, you should select it as the correct answer.